# Programming while loop in C

Tags: c

First, I am a total beginner, so the question is probably very obvious for all of you, but i don't get what's wrong with the while loop in this program. Te aim of the program is to calculate the average between numbers where the user inputs 0 when he wants to continue putting numbers in and inputs 1 when he wants to stop, so the loop is supposed to stop when the user puts 1 and to compute a sum of the values when he enters 0 at the end. So this is what i wrote, i used `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` as libraries :

```
int decision;
int value;
int sum = 0;
float av;
int order = 1;

printf ("for continue press: 0\n ");
printf ("for stopping press: 1\n ");

while (decision == 0) {
    printf("input value:");

    scanf("%d", &value);
    sum = sum + value;

    printf ("continue?");

    scanf("%d", &decision);
    order = order + 1;
}
av = (float) sum / (float) order;

printf("the average is: %.2f", av);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

what the terminal displays is just "the average is:0.00", it skips the whole operation above.

Comment: First `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` are not libraries.

Comment: They are headers from the standard library.

Comment: ok thanks i just started 2 weeks ago and i still struggle to spot mistakes and i don't really know all the terms

Comment: @MicheleGalli - Using a copy/paste response to thank everyone for their answers is not necessary. The tooltip above `add comment` says "avoid comments like '+1' or 'thanks'."

Comment: yes, clearly i'm new to the website as well

Comment: ' I am a total beginner' OK your next step is to learn how to use a debugger.  Don't try to develop any more code until you know how to debug.  The uninitialized var would have been blatantly obvious if stepping through with a debugger.

Answer (score 4):

You should initialize `decision` to 0

```
int decision = 0;
```

so that the while loop is true

```
while (decision == 0) {
```

on the first iteration.

Comment: But prefer an infinite loop with a `break`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath No, I think this is a fine way to use the loop. If possible, I always try to have my loops have meaningful exit conditions. `while(1)` isn't very descriptive.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Why would an infinite loop be preferred?

Comment: Well you could argue that it's a matter of taste (like early `return`s), but if you are interested in my opinion, I prefer to keep the condition and exiting from the loop close by. With the current solution you have to scan the code to figure out what happens with `decision`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I suppose it's a matter of taste, but loops use conditions for a reason. It's silly not to utilize them.

Comment: @PCLuddite: Well, it's silly to test a condition which is always true the first time. Use a `do while` loop then.. which, in this case, would keep the condition and exiting from the loop close by.

Answer (score 1):

In C, declaring a variable does not initialize it. So the initial value of `decision` is more or less random. If it's not zero (and it likely is not), the cycle is never entered.

Perversely, when in "debug mode" or using some instrumentation such as `valgrind`, memory *might* be either zeroed or initialized consistently, leading to "unreproducible" bugs that may be difficult to track. *That is why you really want to always initialize your variables*

Try with:

```
int decision = 0;
```

Also, turn on all compiler warning flags. You want to be warned when such things happen, and the compiler can do so if you tell it to.

## Another way

You do not need `decision` anywhere else, so it's good to have one less variable in the outer scope:

```
for (;;) {
    int decision; /* The variable only lives inside this loop */
    printf("input value:");

    scanf("%d", &value);
    sum = sum + value;

    printf ("continue?");
    scanf("%d", &decision);
    if (0 == decision) {
        break;
    }
    order = order + 1;
}
```

## Notice

If you start `order` from 1, and enter only one value, `order` will be increased to 2, and this will get your calculation off. Either start from 0 or increase the value after decision confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

In C, simply declaring a variable does not assign it a value of `0`. You have to do that. In fact, actually using a variable that has not been initialized is undefined behavior. Most likely, the variable contains whatever contents was in the memory location assigned to it.

The solution is to actually define `decision`.

```
int decision = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the `decision` variable and that is why the error.

```
int decision = 0;
```