# GCC uninitialized variable check not working with `while`?

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-behavior, gcc-warning

I have recently [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33048156/1428679) on C, in which I suggested turning on all compiler warnings.

I thought that I would copy-paste the actual warning that I was sure gcc would have given on compiling the OP's code.

Except **it did not work**. I boiled it down to this test case **which also does not work**:

```
int main() {
        int a; /* not initialised */

        while (a) { /* warn me! */
            a++;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

I would have bet my last penny on `gcc` saying:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:4:6: warning: ‘a’ is used uninitialized in this function   [-Wuninitialized]

 while (a) {
        ^
```

...**and I would have lost**. I get no warning whatsoever! And yet if I use `if` instead of `while`, why yes, *then* I get exactly that warning. But with `while`? Nary a whisper.

I checked out some [reports](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46853) that seemed germane and concluded that while they don't apply, there just might be *something* done by `gcc` that makes the warning superfluous in just this one case. I'd like to know what.

Is it because `a` is initialized to 0? No, because

```
int main() {
    int a;

    if (a == 0) { printf("a is zero\n"); }

    while (a == 0) { a = printf("a is zero\n"); }

    return 0;
}
```

gives an error on the if(), but gives no more errors if I comment the if() out. If gcc knew that a was going to be 0, the first if also should have elicited no error.

So what's happening here?

Comment: Hey, without your duplicate, I wouldn't have read _any_ of these! It's been educational.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug. It's a quality of implementation issue. If we look at the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), it states:

> Note that there may be no warning about a variable that is used only
>   to compute a value that itself is never used, because such
>   computations may be deleted by data flow analysis before the warnings
>   are printed.

Indeed, the following:

```
int b = a++;
```

does elicit a warning.

```
main.cpp:6:16: warning: variable 'a' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
        while (a) { /* warn me! */
               ^

main.cpp:4:14: note: initialize the variable 'a' to silence this warning
        int a; /* not initialised */
             ^
              = 0
```

Original example had `printf`, but that was confusing as it implies relation to the "as-if" rule.

Really, the best thing you can do is:

- Accept that warning about every possible scenario is equivalent to solving the halting problem
- Report it to the developers and hope they do something about it
- Use an alternative. Clang *does* provide a warning
- Look at ["Better Uninitialized Warnings"](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Better_Uninitialized_Warnings) from the GCC wiki. Support the project. Keep in mind that there's two sides to the coin. [GCC is notorious for bogus warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=may%20be%20uninitialized) as well.

Comment: To confirm, you're saying the entire lifetime of `a` has no effects and can be optimised away altogether. Interesting to hear how this can affect warning diagnostics!

Comment: @underscore_d that's not necessarily the case, whether it is optimised out or not isn't related to the lack of warning.

Comment: Yeah, not ideal wording by me. What I meant was the lack of side effects and how I didn't realise some warnings were affected by that.

Comment: fwiw a dupe suggests optimisation might indeed be involved if its output is the input used for flow analysis http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313855/why-does-gcc-only-sometimes-detect-the-use-of-a-variable-before-its-initializati?rq=1

Comment: Actually, this **is** a bug ( https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18501 ). To counter your example, I added `int a, b;` and then assigned a to b, and printf'ed b to stdout, and `gcc -W -Wall` did not even twitch. Possibly in C++ mode the behaviour is different. The duplicate answer however suggests to install **clang** for these checks.